# pthread_yield doesn't properly cycle between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have three functions A, B, C, which I want to use for threading. I want to run them for certain number of iterations and wants to switch between them at every iteration. I am having problem with their order of execution while using pthread_yield()

Below is the code for these functions

```
void *A(void *arg){
int i = 0;
for (i=0; i < 3; i++){
    printf("Hello A%d\n", i);
    pthread_yield();
    }
}

void *B(void *arg){
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i < 3; i++){
        printf("Hello B%d\n", i);
        pthread_yield();
    }
}

void *C(void *arg){
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i < 3; i++){
        printf("Hello C%d\n", i);
        pthread_yield();
    }
}
```

and here is the code for my main function where I make the threads

```
int main(){

    pthread_t threadId_1, threadId_2, threadId_3;

    printf("Before Thread\n"); 
    pthread_create(&threadId_1, NULL, A, NULL); 
    pthread_create(&threadId_2, NULL, B, NULL); 
    pthread_create(&threadId_3, NULL, C, NULL); 
    // This line is Equivalent to Sleep // pthread_join(threadId_1, NULL); 
    //pthread_join(threadId_2, NULL);
    //pthread_join(threadId_3, NULL);
    sleep(1);
    printf("After Thread\n");

}
```

when I run the program I get the following output:

```
Before Thread
Hello C0
Hello B0
Hello C1
Hello B1
Hello C2
Hello B2
Hello A0
Hello A1
Hello A2
After Thread
```

Instead of this I want

```
Before Thread
Hello A0
Hello B0
Hello C0
Hello A1
Hello B1
Hello C1
Hello A2
Hello B2
Hello C2
After Thread
```

If I don't use pthread_yield, the thread I created last will finish first and then the second last and the thread created first will finish last. why is that so?

Also, when I use pthread_yield, why does the program alternates between the last two created threads B and C before finishing the execution and then moving to the thread A?

How can I achieve my desired output where thread A, B, C perfectly alternates between each other?

Comment: I am using c++.

Comment: If you don't use pthread_yeild(), the threads can execute in any order, you might try adding more iterations to your loop and check the results. pthread_yeild() puts the current thread in waiting queue and schedules another thread to run.Now, any one of A0,B0,C0 can be printed first as you have made 3 calls to A,B and C from main. Let's suppose a call is made to C first, then, C0 will be printed,the thread will go back to the waiting queue and another thread will get executed which can be A or B(any one of "A0" or "B0" can be printed). So ,this approach is not correct for the results you need.

Comment: From the documentation: "pthread_yield() is intended for use with real-time scheduling policies (i.e., SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR).  Use of pthread_yield() with nondeterministic scheduling policies such as SCHED_OTHER is unspecified and very likely means your application design is broken."

Comment: @AkshitAchara you are right. Previously I tried with 3 to 10 iterations. Now I tried with 100 iterations. For the first few iterations only B and C gets scheduled and then A also started getting scheduled. I am surprised that in order to see the 'desirable' results I need to increase the number of iterations.

Comment: Where does it say it should 'properly cycle between threads'?

Answer (score 3):

[`man pthread_yield`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_yield.3.html) :

> causes the calling thread to relinquish the CPU.  The  thread is placed at the end of the run queue for its static priority and another thread is scheduled to run. **If the calling thread is the only thread in the highest priority list at that time, it will continue to run.**

In other words, `pthread_yield` doesn't guarantee suspending the thread. And, hence, it cannot help order or serialize the execution of threads. It is a wrong tool for your task.

---

> I have three functions A, B, C, which I want to use for threading. I want to run them for certain number of iterations and wants to switch between them at every iteration.

One solution is to have one thread running functions A, B and C in sequence one after another.

Another solution could be to pin the threads to the same CPU and assign real-time FIFO priority, so that `pthread_yield` switches to another FIFO real-time thread waiting to run on the same CPU. However, parallelism is lost in this case, defeating the purpose of having multiple threads in the first place.

Comment: People who come from hard real-time systems often expect more control and determinism than e.g. Linux gives. Often, the Pthreads and Posix mechanisms are just too loosely defined (for good reason). One thing that makes Linux more close to hard real-time is SCHED_DEADLINE.